# new Date('december 2019') is not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to compare two dates and  am using

> new Date('december 2019')

and it is not working in react js / react native

```
        var resultList = [];
        var dated = new Date('december 2019');
        var endDated = new Date('march 2020');
        var monthNameList = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

        while (dated <= endDated)
        {
            console.log('checking');
            var stringDate = monthNameList[dated.getMonth()] + " " + dated.getFullYear() + " Qist is " + this.state.qistprice;
            resultList.push(stringDate);
            dated.setMonth(dated.getMonth()+1);
        }
```

in vanilla javascript it is working fine . but in react native it is not working if i try using format like that

> new Date('december 13, 2019')
>   then it will work but i dont want that i just want 'december 2019' to work .. is there any way around ?

code that i have tried in vanilla js is this

```js
var resultList = [];
    var dated = new Date('december 2019');
    var endDated = new Date('march 2020');
    var monthNameList = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    while (dated <= endDated)
    {
      console.log('checking');
      var stringDate = monthNameList[dated.getMonth()] + " " + dated.getFullYear() ;
      resultList.push(stringDate);
      dated.setMonth(dated.getMonth()+1);
    }
    console.log(resultList)
```

Comment: What *date* is "december 2019" supposed to be anyway? `Date` objects are specific *to the second*…!

Comment: Why don't you just use `new Date('december 01, 2019')`? It's the same

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek because it's similarly non-standard?

Comment: @VLAZ I know, it's another case. But OP asks for something else. I don't know his reasons nor project his working on. Maybe it's just how it has to be? Who knows? The result of `new Date('december 01, 2019')` will be the same

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I'd avoid suggesting non-standard date formats. There are already enough problems with handling dates, no need to contribute to them.

Comment: @VLAZ Ok, I get your point.

Comment: @samairali better to use a lib instead of handling this by hand example https://date-fns.org/ the `Date` implem depend on the runtime env and can give you some supprises

Comment: @samairali You still have to define *which day* of december you wish to use for your date object. If it doesn't matter, just use the first by adding the hard-coded "01" to your input syntax.

Comment: @h1b9b basically the issue and the problem i want to understand is it is working perfectly in vanila js ... it s not working in react js only

Comment: What exactly does it do differently in React?

Comment: @deceze it doesnot work , it doesnot create array as it is creating in vanila js code snippet that is have added ...

Comment: Debug that in more depth. Is the `Date` object created different…? That would be surprising, but I'm not going to rule it out. You can create a snippet here including React to demonstrate such behaviour.

Comment: @deceze if you use the exact same code 100% exact same code as i have pasted in the snippet then it will not work .... it will not create an array the end result is not same ...

Comment: FWIW, the above snippet doesn't even work as is in my browser…

Comment: http://prntscr.com/qti5gq    you are not seeing it like that ?

Comment: Nope. **Because you're asking the `Date` constructor to parse a _non-standard date_, and the result of that will depend on individual browsers.**

Comment: hmm so at the end of the day we can not achieve it as i want ?

Comment: No, you can't just throw any random string at `Date` and get "what you mean" from it.

Comment: okay got it ... actually i was getting it in vanila js that is why i was confused ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js library.

```
moment('december 2019').format('L')
"12/01/2019"
```

[image]

Comment: Adding additional libraries isnt the solution for every problem...

Comment: new Date() is also working.

Comment: @AnkitKumarRajpoot basically the issue and the problem i want to understand is it is working perfectly in vanila js ... it s not working in react js/ native only

Comment: Wait, i am testing.

Comment: you can go here for testing ... https://jsbin.com/micodudose/edit?html,console

Comment: Besides moment.js is huge, if you must there are tons of lighter libraries out there

Comment: If you use new Date().getMonth() it will work fine.

Comment: There are multiple methods in react native, if u will use them than it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you should use momentjs (https://momentjs.com/) library to manipulate and handle the Date in your application. Native Date() object is really hard to manage and very off I had problems with it.

I can't help you now with native Date, but for a short answer, I recommend to use momentjs.